# Не могу понять кусок кода

Tags: javascript

Решил разобрать маленький фреймворк Sortable (для сортировки элементов на странице) и не могу понять небольшой кусок кода

```
(function Sortable (factory) {})(function sortableFactory() {})
```

Сам JavaScript более-менее знаю, а вот тут встал в ступор... Разжуйте идиоту, пожалуйста, как устроена логика в этом коде...

Answer (score 0):

приведенный вами код смысла не имеет, он просто выполняет функцию Sortable с аргументом в виде другой функции, ничего не возвращает, ни какие переменные во внешних Scope не задает.

Но, если вы об этом: 
https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/blob/master/Sortable.js#L7

```
(function sortableModule(factory) {
    "use strict";

    if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define(factory);
    }
    else if (typeof module != "undefined" && typeof module.exports != "undefined") {
        module.exports = factory();
    }
    else {
        /* jshint sub:true */
        window["Sortable"] = factory();
    }
})(function sortableFactory() { .....
```

то тут все просто, фабрика по какой-то причине должна быть инициализирована, она возвращает интерфейс для работы с модулем, т.к. у нас зоопарк модульных имплементаций, нужно этот интерфейс экспортировать для текущей системы модулей, она как-то там выбирается в анонимке, в результате в выбранную глобальную среду экспортируется только интерфейс.

Я бы так делать не стал, вместо этого я сделал бы просто npm модуль, а для браузера собрал бы webpack или browserify например. Это, кроме всего прочего, позволит использовать модульность и в самой библиотечке.

Comment: т.е. если функция взята в скобки, то она выполняется автоматически? А вторая скобка передает аргументы для этой функции?

Comment: да, вы разве не встречали конструкцию ?
`(function(text) {console.log(text)})('Hello World');`

Comment: можно и так
`(function(text){console.log(text)}('Hello World'));`
и даже так 
`!function(text){console.log(text)}('Hello World');` (последний случай вернет `true`) всё дело в операторе

Comment: Честно говоря, сколько книг перечитал - впервые вижу такое, спасибо за объяснения.

Comment: плохие книги, это типичная анонимка, может в книгах было такое:
`var func = function(){}` ? так вот, в js все что можно присвоить можно использовать как ссылку, например: `new Image().src="https://sss"` (не обязательно создавать переменную, достаточно ссылки)

Comment: "т.е. если функция взята в скобки, то она выполняется автоматически?" не совссем так - функция создается (ссылка на нее), выполняется как раз потому, что присутствуют вторые скобки.

Comment: вот например анонимный класс :)
`(new class {test(){console.log("hello world")}}).test()`